# How to check Firefox version when running Selenium tests in Jenkins?

Tags: selenium

Selenium plug has integrated Firefox. I would like to know how to check version of Firefox.

Comment: Selenium doesn't integrate Firefox.

Comment: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Selenium+Plugin
read this before pasting odd comments

Comment: The Jenkins plugin has nothing to do with it! Selenium doesn't integrate or bundle Firefox! It's a Firefox extension!

Comment: Just say how to check which version of Firefox is there!!! RAPIDLY!!!

Comment: The below answer will do that for you. If you aren't a developer of some kind, it's time to crack open some books and learn.

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy. You should use the browser capatibilities. But it's not a plugin.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

Capabilities caps = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
String browserName = caps.getBrowserName();
String browserVersion = caps.getVersion();
System.out.println(browserName+" "+browserVersion);
```

Comment: Sorry, I am not a developer. I have my Jenkins running in my browser, so I would like to know if there is any button or something else...

Comment: There is no such a button, unfortunately. How do you run tests?  You may ask a developer to add this code to tests. Jenkins runs everything as if it was run from command line and displays what the app would display in command line. So, a user should manage what to display in Jenkins by himself. Jenkins is not responsible for that.

Comment: I run my tests from Jenkins web interface, it interacts with test suites and gives me output in "Console Output".

Answer (score 2):

From Firefox version 48 and forward, [geckodriver capabilites](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver) are in place. With selenium you can get the Firefox version number using "browserVersion", like in this Python example:

```
driver.capabilities['browserVersion']
```