# Use of Selenium 3.0 with Firefox V<47

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

`Selenium3` supports executable `geckodriver` to launch `Mozilla Firefox` just like other drivers; but executable `geckodriver` is not compatible with `Mozilla Firefox < v47`.

So How can we achieve backward compatibility with browsers `V<47` i,e how can we use `firefox` browsers `V<47` with `Selenium3`.

Answer (score 4):

Disable the `geckodriver` capabilities so that `FirefoxDriver` can be used.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "path/to/geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities d = new DesiredCapabilities();
d.setCapability("marionette", false);  // to disable marionette, by default true
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(d);
```

---

**Little Background to geckodriver.exe and Firefox version support:**

From `geckodriver` github page:

```
Firefox 47 is explicitly not supported
```

So, If you want to use `<= Firefox 47` version, use `Firefox driver` but not `geckodriver`.

1. In case of selenium 2.53, you don't need to do any additional things (no need to setup `geckodriver` as `selenium 2.53` uses `Firefox driver` by `default`).
2. In Selenium 3.0, we must set `geckodriver` path (as `geckodriver` is the `default` driver for `Firefox` in `Selenium 3.0`) using `System.setProperty` and set `marionette` to `false`, so `geckodriver` capabilities will be disabled and default Firefox driver is used.

References:

1. https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver#supported-firefoxen
2. https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/224
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40658421/2575259

Comment: do we have some kind of flexibility in code like same code for ff v>47 and ff <47 or placing some condition to make generic code???

Comment: You can use 'getVersion' method. So add if else block to achieve your task. More details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556163/get-browser-version-using-selenium-webdriver

Comment: I'm trying to migrate to Selenium 3.X but the geckodriver was the main obstacle. Now I know how to deal with that. Your solution save my day. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use old `FirefoxDriver`, just make sure to set marionette on false if you are using RemoteDriver because I'm not sure is it enabled by default (`caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.MARIONETTE, false);`)

This driver doesn't need any `.exe` file, just `import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;` in your code so you could use it.

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

or if you are using grid:

```
driver = RemoteWebDriver(url, DesiredCapabilities.firefox());
```