# Which Firefox browser versions supported for given Geckodriver version?

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, geckodriver

I regularly update Firefox and Chrome browser, current version 54.0.1 32 bit So which version of Geckodriver to be used.
I tried with both version `Geckodriver-v0.18.0 and geckodriver-v0.16.1`

For future reference where can I find the list the supported firefox browsers with respective geckodriver versions

**Note: No any code changes in launch browser**

Previous the code was working with geckodriver-v0.16.1 for older firefox versions
Now getting exception after updating firefox 54.0.1 and Geckodriver-v0.18.0 :

> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect
>   to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>   oundUpdates":1,"bootstrap":false,"skinnable":false,"size":3242616,"sourceURI":null,"releaseNotesURI":null,"softDisabled":false,"foreignInstall":true,"hasBinaryComponents":false,"strictCompatibility":false,"locales":[],"targetApplications":[{"id":"{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}","minVersion":"1.5","maxVersion":"9.9"}],"targetPlatforms":[],"multiprocessCompatible":false,"signedState":0,"seen":true,"dependencies":[],"hasEmbeddedWebExtension":false,"mpcOptedOut":false,"userPermissions":null}

Comment: Use latest firefox browser, gecko driver and selenium 3.4. It would work fine

Comment: Can u please help with versions @santhoshkumar
I am currently using:firefox -54.0.1 32 bit, Gecko driver - v0.18.0 and Selenium 3.4.0

Comment: Yes. The above versions also should work. I am using Fire54.0 , gecko 0.19 and selenium 3.4

Answer (score 27):

This Question have been surfacing out quite often for sometime now since we migrated from the legacy *Firefox* releases to **Marionette** based *Mozilla Firefox* releases (beginning with *Firefox 48*). It is not clear what exactly you mean by *the code was working with geckodriver-v0.16.1 for older firefox versions.*

In general, each *GeckoDriver* release supports each version of *Mozilla Firefox* releases (beginning with Firefox 48) where the property **marionette** needs to be set to **`true`** (either by *default* or through *configuration*)

If you are working with the legacy *Firefox* releases (till *Firefox 47.x*) *GeckoDriver* still works but you have to explicitly set the property **marionette** to **`false`**

Now, the only dependency which exists, is between *GeckoDriver* and *Selenium* releases. The *GeckoDriver* release notes clearly mentions all the major/minor **New Feature Addition**, **Enhancements**,**Bug Fixes** and **Download Location** separately in [this link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases).

The last announced dependency was:

> Note that **`geckodriver v0.16.0`** is only compatible with **`Selenium 3.4 and greater`**.

---

### [*GeckoDriver*, *Selenium* and *Firefox Browser* compatibility chart](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html)

[image: geckodriver_versions]

Answer (score 5):

The canonical source of this information is published by Mozilla in the official geckodriver documentation.  The docs are updated with each new geckodriver release.

The main documentation link is located here:

- https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/index.html

... and specifically, see the "Supported platforms" page here:

- https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/geckodriver/Support.html

It contains a mapping between geckodriver releases, supported versions of Firefox, and required Selenium versions.