# TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url' error using GeckoDriver and Firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, positional-argument

Executing below code in pycharm.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Error:

```
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 2):

Specify the path the chrome driver is located in for example when calling

```
webdriver.Firefox(‘C://Users/Username/Downloads/‘)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\Rishabh\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
```

Alternate code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\Rishabh\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I got this error for not using parenthesis **()**.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with braces while creating Firefox instance. see below example.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()   #focus on () at the end
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor is **`driver = webdriver.Firefox()`**. So in your code block you need to replace `driver = webdriver.Firefox` with:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Additionally, you may need to pass the *absolute path* of the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) binary as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused bacause there are not,()pharentesis, put the pharantesis end to the line

Check this
In Selenium and python
driver = webdriver.Chrome()