# Browser.get() method can't get the URL. This code is a part of a Python code

Tags: python, linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

OS:- Kali linux 2019.1
Firefox 60.6.1
Geckodriver :- 0.18.0
selenium 3.5.2

The code gets stuck after the browser.get line. When I check the geckodriver logs..it shows > ddons.productaddons   WARN    Failed downloading via XHR, status: 0, reason: error (Don't Know if it is relevant)

I tried changing the " to ' for the URL, Tried changing browser.get to browser.navigate.to with no success. The URL works fine. I can open it in firefox browser. It also doesn't take a lot of time to open. So, doesn't seem to be a wait() issue.

# `------------[STARTS A WEBSERVER + FORWARDS PORT WITH NGROK]-------------` #

```
os.system('xterm -e "cd ./WEBSERVER/ && php -S 127.0.0.1:80" &')
os.system("./ngrok http 80 > /dev/null &")




time.sleep(3)
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,executable_path='base/geckodriver')
browser.get("http://localhost:4040/status")
time.sleep(5)
url_f=str(browser.find_element_by_css_selector("li.list-unstyled:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > table:nth-child(2) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(2)").text)
browser.close()
show_url = str(url_f)


# `GENERATES EMAIL TEMPLATE


emaildata = str(EMAIL1_TW)
emaildata = emaildata.replace('_EF', str(UNAME))
emaildata = emaildata.replace('G_URL', str(n_url))
emaildata = emaildata.replace('Windows 7', str(Email_OS))
emaildata = emaildata.replace('Antartica', str(Email_from))


# `DECIDES THE EMAIL ADDRESS

from_email = str(random.choice(['JohnSpencer@Kolear.com','no-reply@kolear.com']))



##################################
#      SENDS  EMAIL       #
##################################


subprocess.call(['sendemail', '-f', from_email,'-t', str(Email), '-u', 'Notice for you', '-m', emaildata, '-s', smtps+":"+port, '-o', 'tls=no','-xu', username, '-xp', password])
os.system('reset')
```

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace

Comment: If you navigating to a URL, why are you using `get`? it should be `go(url)` instead.

Comment: This code is within a python code. I don't know how to run a stack trace in this case.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question. This is missing too much information, the question is somewhat ambiquitious, and the formatting needs revision

Comment: @AlexanderFalk added the OS version, firefox version, selenium version, geckodriver version...If you are referring to a stack trace..I mentioned ..this is within a python code..I don't know how to run stack in this case.

Comment: @ShivamPandey can't find any such command.

Comment: @DebanjanB How to run it ..if this code is within a python code?

Comment: Why is python code tagged with Java, @user240163? Seems to me this has nothing to do with Java? Or are you running a script embedded from Java? In that case? Why?

Comment: **error stack trace** -> the error trace logs that appear within the console

Comment: @AlexanderFalk Thank you for your patience. I have updated the code for the bigger picture. If this question has wrong attributions, I will delete it and post it in Python..I don't think though..this is a python issue. I searched many questions with the same issue..they were all related to either the Java code or the selenium/firefox versions.

Comment: @DebanjanB No errors appear in the console. I am debugging this with pdb. It does nothing after the browser.get line. So maybe it is not an issue with Java code but similar questions had solutions with the code and sometimes with selenium/firefox version specific code changes. I wasn't sure so I tagged it in Java as well.

Comment: @DebanjanB So, Gecko is 0.18.0 which is compatible with selenium 3.5(>3.4) which is compatible with firefox 60.6.1(52-62)...??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error trace logs would have helped us to debug the issue in a better way. However your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries which you are using:

- Firefox v60.6.1
- Geckodriver v0.18.0
- Selenium v3.5.2

If you are using *GeckoDriver*-*Selenium*-*Firefox* combo, you need to follow the following compatibility chart:

[image: supported_platforms_geckodriver_24]

> You can find a detailed discussion in [Which Firefox browser versions supported for given Geckodriver version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403)

Comment: So, Gecko is 0.18.0 which is compatible with selenium 3.5(>3.4) which is compatible with firefox 60.6.1(52-62)...??