# Selenium Firefox Python running in headless mode Timeout on initializing driver

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, firefox-headless

- Firefox version: 60.9.0esr (32-bit)
- Selenium version: 3.141.0
- Geckodriver version: 0.24.0 (32-bit)

So everything currently works in non-headless mode. But I need to run this python script in a GUI-less linux server (thus need headless mode). For some reason, all my attempts to run headlessly results in selenium web driver timing out on initialization.

```
        from selenium import webdriver

        geckoDriverFilepath = path + "geckodriver24_32.exe"

        opts = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        opts.add_argument("--headless")
        opts.add_argument("--width=2560")
        opts.add_argument("--height=1440")

        #initialize driver (breaks/timeouts here)
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts,executable_path=geckoDriverFilepath)
```

The following is the Traceback:

> File "c:\Users\xUser\Desktop\BOMWebService\Backend\code\FirefoxStarter.py", line 51, in StartFirefox
>       driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=opts,executable_path=geckoDriverFilepath)
>
> File "C:\Users\xUser\Desktop\BOMWebService\Backend\virEnvBOMBackend\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 174, in **init**
>       keep_alive=True)
>
> File "C:\Users\xUser\Desktop\BOMWebService\Backend\virEnvBOMBackend\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in **init**
>       self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
>
> File "C:\Users\xUser\Desktop\BOMWebService\Backend\virEnvBOMBackend\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
>       response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
>
> File "C:\Users\xUser\Desktop\BOMWebService\Backend\virEnvBOMBackend\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>
> File "C:\Users\xUser\Desktop\BOMWebService\Backend\virEnvBOMBackend\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: timed out

Any pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That's a pretty old version of firefox (and I don't know that the geckodriver is the corresponding driver).  Is there a reason that you don't want to use current version?  And you say you want to run on linux, but your stacktrace is for Windows...

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: timed out
```

...implies that the **GeckoDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Firefox Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is **3.141.0** which is almost a bit older.
- Your *GeckoDriver* version is *v0.24.0*.
- Your *Firefox* version is *v60.9.0esr*.

So there is a clear mismatch between *Selenium Client v3.141.0* , *GeckoDriver v0.24.0* and the *Firefox Browser v60.9.0esr*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.26.0**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0) level.
- GeckoDriver is present in the desired location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v70.0*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

> Here you can find a detailed discussion on [Which Firefox browser versions supported for given Geckodriver version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403)