# System.InvalidOperationException: 'Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location error using Firefox Selenium in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium in C# and I get the following error,

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Expected browser binary location,
> but unable to find binary in default location, no
> 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag
> set on the command line (SessionNotCreated)'

what could it be?

Comment: Do you have installed Firefox? If yes, is the gecko driver installed?

Comment: i install selenium firefox , what is gecko driver?

Comment: Maybe that helps: https://www.guru99.com/gecko-marionette-driver-selenium.html

Comment: i am using this site and its not say about this . https://www.codeproject.com/articles/877519/using-selenium-webdriver-with-tor-csharp-code

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line (SessionNotCreated)'
```

...implies that the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Firefox Browser* session.

Possibly [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) browser is installed at a non-conventional location, hence *GeckoDriver* is unable to access the `firefox` binary.

---

### Solution

As a solution pass the *absolute location* of the `firefox.exe` binary through the **`BrowserExecutableLocation`** argument of `FirefoxOptions` as follows:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.BrowserExecutableLocation = ("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe"); //location where Firefox is installed
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need download Mozilla Firefox

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/

then install Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: i download selenium firefox , i want open tor with selenium

Comment: Did you install Firefox in default location?

Comment: i have tor browser in my desktop. yes i have firefox

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/877519/using-selenium-webdriver-with-tor-csharp-code