# How to remove errors with chromedriver? The following errors appear everytime(both the python file and driver are in the same folder)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Chrome process.
```

Comment: Your code trials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
options = Options()

options.headless = False
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX``

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp, options=options,capabilities=cap)
```

Comment: I had to add these lines and this works well with Firefox.(Not sure about others)

Comment: `cap["marionette"] = False` isn't a solution when you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) initiated [tag:firefox] _Browsing Context_

Comment: @DebanjanB , Yes, that was a comment line, but now i have removed it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set chrome driver capabilities and path before launching the driver.
More details here : https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities

Comment: This didn't work for me either . It still showed the same errors

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach. No need to maintain chromedriver in your project folder. Just 2 lines of code. Refer here [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/)