# TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] :

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I am trying to connect to my firefox browser with selenium.

```
#Initialise Firefox
print("here")
locationofDriver = "C:/Users/barry/OneDrive/Documents/Webdriver/"
print("here2")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(locationofDriver)
print("here3")
```

Yet I get two errors:

```
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

And:

```
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond', None, 10060, None))
```

The Output from the print statements:

```
here
here2
```

I launched Firefox manually to see if their was an issue, however it is perfectly functional
The web-driver is in the correct place.
[image]

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead providing only the location of the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) executable you need to provide the *absolute path* of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) / [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) along with the extension i.e. `.exe`. So your effective code block will be:

- For *ChromeDriver*:

  ```
  locationofDriver = r'C:/Users/barry/OneDrive/Documents/Webdriver/chromedriver.exe'
  ```
- For *GeckoDriver*:

  ```
  locationofDriver = r'C:/Users/barry/OneDrive/Documents/Webdriver/geckodriver.exe'
  ```

Finally, you can pass the *key* `executable_path`along the *value* as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=locationofDriver)
```

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
locationofDriver = "<path to file>/geckodriver.exe"
```

Or add `geckodriver.exe` to directory with working python file and then you can try:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Comment: I get the error NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:/Users/barry/OneDrive/Documents/Webdriver/geckodriver.exe'

Comment: Check your path to `geckodriver.exe`. You must write correct path to this file. Try add `geckodriver.exe` to directory with working python file.