# firefox-headless contol box is missing from screenshot - selenium - linux

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, firefox-headless

I am facing exactly same problem https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1358.

Firefox-headless mode screenshots taken from linux are missing  input box

Question:

Do we have any alternative to solve this problem. I am using FF 83

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved using firefox settings.

`widget.disable-native-theme-for-content` to `true`

Reference :

https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/k2nghh/any_alternatives_for_firefoxlinuxheadless/

PS: Credit goes to [reddit user](https://www.reddit.com/user/evilpies/) who answered my question :)

I verified it is working.

Answer (score 0):

You saw it right. For [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) initiated [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) [Screenshot in headless mode doesn't show form controls correctly](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1358).

This issue was closed as the original issue is with Firefox and being tracked through [Some input field are black when taking screenshot in headless mode](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1385711) is specific to [linux](/questions/tagged/linux) platform where `@Michael Smith` mentioned:

> It looks like this is a result of an nsITheme object not being created
> in headless mode under
> [GTK](http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/0f16d437cce97733c6678d29982a6bcad49f817b/widget/gtk/nsWidgetFactory.cpp#90-92),
> as nsNativeThemeGTK depends on APIs which we can't access in headless
> mode. As a result this shouldn't affect the Windows and macOS
> platforms.

Further he detailed:

> We have existing fallback paths for when a nsITheme object is
> unavailable, but it looks like they're not being exercised on any of
> Windows, macOS, or Linux under normal conditions. For example, the
> width of the dropdown button is determined by the width of the
> scrollbar in the dropdown list. This is measured by
> [GetNondisappearingScrollbarWidth](http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/0f16d437cce97733c6678d29982a6bcad49f817b/layout/generic/nsGfxScrollFrame.cpp#1217),
> which boils down to asking [the vertical scrollbar nsBoxFrame what its
> preferred width
> is](http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/generic/nsGfxScrollFrame.cpp#1197).
> Normally this ends up being calculated using
> nsITheme::GetMinimumWidgetSize which calls out to platform-specific
> code; in the absence of a theme, we rely on the computed size from the
> CSS applied to the scrollbar XUL element and its children. Note that
> [vertical scrollbar thumbs have a minimum height
> assigned](http://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/c329d562fb6c6218bdb79290faaf015467ef89e2/toolkit/themes/windows/global/xulscrollbars.css#49),
> but no minimum width, so the computed scrollbar width ends up being 0,
> and the dropdown buttons end up being 0-width. Adding a minimum width
> to thumb[orient="vertical"] causes the dropdown buttons to show up
> under headless mode. It also causes the scrollbar to show up along the
> side, but there's no color set for the slider, so it's just a white
> strip.

---

### Conclusion

This issue was assigned **Priority 3** and is still in **Open** state with no alternatives.