# 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH using GeckoDriver and Firefox through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm very familiar with using chromedriver for selenium, im now trying to using geckdriver instead but for some reason I keep getting the error `'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

I followed the steps in [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

- I added gecko driver to path in environment variables
- I updated firefox to the latest version
- I used the binary method
- Put the geckodriver in my folder where my script is
- I restarted my computer

But none of these methods seem to work, is there something I'm missing?

Here's my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary


binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\\Users\\ojadi\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.28.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe")
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download and store the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) executable anywhere with in your system and you need to do pass the absolute path of `firefox` binary through the attribute `binary_location` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\\ojadi\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.28.0-win64\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('http://google.com/')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Two settings which are often overlooked in installation guides:**

1. Including geckodriver executable in your profile
2. Enabling geckodriver executable

**MAC: To add geckodriver to your profile:**

1. Open your zsh profile: `open ~/.zshrc`
2. Add the following line of code to your profile: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/geckodriver` *(Assuming this is the location of your geckodriver, if not, replace with location.)*
3. Save and close.
4. Reload your profile (or restart terminal): `source ~/.zshrc`

**MAC: To make geckodriver executable:**

1. `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/geckodriver` (or path to geckodriver exectable)

Comment: Thanks but I am a windows user not mac