# Selenium- Class FirefoxDriver issue : The method FirefoxDriver(FirefoxOptions) is undefined

Tags: java, selenium, testng, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am facing this issue when i want to set Firefox preferences as follows :

```java
public class MyTest{
    
    public WebDriver driver;
    public String baseUrl;
    
    @BeforeSuite
    public void beforeSuite() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        //FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        options.addPreference("browser.download.folderList", 1);
        options.addPreference("browser.download.dir", "C:\\Downloads");
        options.addPreference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", true);
        options.addPreference("browser.download.viewableInternally.enabledTypes", "");
        options.addPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf;text/plain;application/text;text/xml;application/xml");
        options.addPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);

        WebDriver driver = FirefoxDriver(options);
       //some other code
```

And the issue is for FirefoxDriver(options) . It underlines `The method FirefoxDriver(FirefoxOptions) is undefined for the type MyTest`

Anyone can give a support on that ?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
```

As well as set the path of the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) using the `System.setProperty()` line as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe");
```

Additionally, to make the *FirefoxOptions* put into effect, you need to remove the line:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

and finally change the line:

```
WebDriver driver = FirefoxDriver(options);
```

as:

```
driver = FirefoxDriver(options);
```

---

Historically this error message...

```
FirefoxDriver(FirefoxOptions) is undefined for the type MyTest
```

...was observed earlier due to:

- Co-existance of older versions of Selenium.
- Incompatibility between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u271](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *GeckoDriver* is upgraded to [GeckoDriver v0.28.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0) level.
- *Firefox* is upgraded to current *Firefox v78.0.2* levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Package is imported but the issue is happening

Comment: @Chaoui05 Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I don't have to set System properties as the webdriver is in my environment variables. What do you mean by "execute your test" ? For the rest, yes. I maybe have to check all the versions..

Comment: @Chaoui05 Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 0):

you can try.

WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();

Answer (score 0):

Remove first

```
    driver= new Firefoxdriver()
```

And change last line as

```
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

If you don't call new you are referring to a function called FirefoxDriver which doesn't ,

You are creating an object of class FirefoxDriver so you should use new keyword