# Selenium starts the browser but shows an error as Message: Can not connect to the Service

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

The code starts the browser, stops at this step (line 5), and after a while throws an error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can not connect to the Service C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

s = Service(r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
myPageTitle = driver.title
print(myPageTitle)
driver.quit()
```

Firefox - 95.0.2
Selenium - 4.1.0

I tried with chrome, same problem

Does anyone know what the problem is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an argument to *`Service()`* instead of the [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) executable, you need to pass the absolute location of the [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329528/which-firefox-browser-versions-supported-for-given-geckodriver-version/45331403#45331403) executable which can be downloaded from [mozilla/geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) page.

So your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

s = Service(r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=s)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
myPageTitle = driver.title
print(myPageTitle)
driver.quit()
```