# I can't open firefox using geckodriver.exe

Tags: selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I'm beginner of selenium.
I want to open firefox using geckodriver.exe.

Here is my code.

```py
from selenium import webdriver

import os
path = os.getcwd() 
firefox_driver_path = str(path)

browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_driver_path)
```

I have confirmed that geckodriver.exe is in the same directory.

Error code

```
Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
​
```

I couldn't find a clear resolution to the above error.

I'm sorry, but please tell me why this error happened and how to resolve it.

Environment: Windows11, Python 3.8.8, selenium-4.1.2

Comment: `path = os.getcwd()` can you confirm [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) is stored there?

Comment: Yes. I have geckodriver.exe file in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this trouble by updating geckodriver.exe to newer version.