# Geckodriver error in Selenium script. Geckodriver is installed correctly, but I get 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I can't understand why geckodriver doesn't work and why the path doesn't exist. I use Ubuntu and Firefox, I uninstalled and reinstalled geckodriver and Firefox-geckodriver. I checked the version and I use `geckodriver 0.30.0` (d372710b98a6 2021-09-16 10:29 +0300). I have already tried uninstalling and installing with

```
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.30.0/geckodriver-v0.30.0-linux64.tar.gz
tar -xvzf geckodriver-v0.30.0- linux64.tar.gz 
chmod + x geckodriver 
export PATH = $ PATH: / path-to-extracted-file /
```

I also installed

```
sudo apt install firefox-geckodriver
```

I try to run this little script, but I get the error:

```
raise WebDriverException (
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Code

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
import os

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
profile_path = '/home/jack/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Browser/profile.default'

options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '127.0.0.1')
options.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 9050)
options.set_preference("network.proxy.socks_remote_dns", False)

service = Service('/usr/bin/geckodriver')
driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)

driver.get("www.google.com")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: in `PATH` it has to be path to folder with `geckodriver` - `/usr/bin`, not path to file `geckodriver` - `/usr/bin/geckodriver`. I have on `PATH` folder in my home `/home/furas/bin` and in this folder I put all needed programs or scripts (in Python, Perl, Ruby, etc)

Comment: you may have to add to `PATH` in `.bashrc` so it would set it everytime when you restart computer

Comment: I have `geckodriver` in folder `/home/furas/bin/` and when I use `Service('/home/furas/bin/geckodriver')` then it works. Maybe you don't have `geckodriver` in folder `/usr/bin/` but in different folder - maybe full path is `/usr/bin/geckodriver/geckodriver` or maybe you put file in home folder. You should first check if you can run `/usr/bin/geckodriver --version` in console/terminal to see version.

Comment: see also module [webdriver_manager](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager) which can check if you have correct driver and download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some ambiguity about the path/location where [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) is getting downloaded which may not be in *`PATH`* / *deafault location*.

In such cases as *`@furas`* suggested the easiest way out is to use the [**Webdriver Manager**](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager).

Sample code:

- *Selenium 3* compatible code:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
  ```
- *Selenium 4* compatible code:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
  from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
  ```

Comment: Thank you. Tomorrow I will read calmly and carefully and try