# [Parent][PImageBridgeParent] Error: RunMessage(msgname=PImageBridge::Msg_WillClose) Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, jbehave

I have a simple java project using Slenium and JBehave for automation testing.
My simple "open a page" code still worked last week but today the code run fine but the end of the execution I get this error message:
`[Parent][PImageBridgeParent] Error: RunMessage(msgname=PImageBridge::Msg_WillClose) Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost`
I don't find anything on web, I have no idea what to do to get green execution.

Full log:

```
org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$RunningStoriesFailed: Failures in running stories: ReportsCount[scenarios=8,scenariosFailed=3,scenariosNotAllowed=0,scenariosPending=0,stepsFailed=3,stories=9,storiesNotAllowed=0,storiesPending=0]
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$ThrowingRunningStoriesFailed.handleFailures(Embedder.java:557)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.handleFailures(Embedder.java:279)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.generateReportsView(Embedder.java:266)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.generateReportsView(Embedder.java:247)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.runStoriesAsPaths(Embedder.java:223)
at org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories.run(JUnitStories.java:20)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54) 
Process finished with exit code 255`
```

I use geckodriver-v0.30.0-macos,Firefox version: 99.0 which is up-to-date

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't see the error within the error stacktrace

Comment: @undetectedSelenium 1649681318353 Marionette INFO Stopped listening on port 52991

###!!! [Parent][PImageBridgeParent] Error: RunMessage(msgname=PImageBridge::Msg_WillClose) Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
```

...implies that most likely there was a crash of Firefox and it can be due to various reasons. In majority of the cases version mismatch between [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447), [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) and [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox)

However, as you are seeing this error at the end of the execution you don't have to worry about unless it is causing your test to fail.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1376)
- [[Child][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1732)

---

### tl; dr

[Intermittent TEST-UNEXPECTED-TIMEOUT | /html/semantics/embedded-content/the-img-element/image-loading-lazy-below-viewport-dynamic.html | TestRunner hit external timeout (this may indicate a hang)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1754557)

Comment: Thank you for the help.
I find these links but I think there are no solution for my problem.

The tests are running fine but after in the AfterStories when Stopped listening on port 64402 I get this error message:

###!!! [Parent][PImageBridgeParent] Error: RunMessage(msgname=PImageBridge::Msg_WillClose) Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost

After it the printout said that the reports generated.

And after I also get jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder RunningStoriesFailed exception:
org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder$RunningStoriesFailed

Comment: Possibly a [known issue](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1235#issuecomment-377765596) See [details](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1235).

Comment: The weird thing was that it worked last week.
I am using lots of Thread.sleep(). Could it case the problem? Can I overload a counter with it?