# contentEncodingError when opening website in Firefox using selenium and python3

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, content-encoding

I'm trying to perform a fairly simple action using Selenium, namely opening google images in Firefox browser.
I also use a proxy server running on the localhost.

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.proxy import Proxy, ProxyType

options = FirefoxOptions()
service = Service()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.accept_insecure_certs = True 

proxy = Proxy({
    'httpProxy': proxy_addr,
    'sslProxy': proxy_addr,
    'proxyType': ProxyType.MANUAL
})

options.proxy = proxy

b = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
b.execute("get", {'url': 'http://images.google.com'})
```

But unfortunately, I'm getting an error like this:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error
> page:
> about:neterror?e=contentEncodingError&u=https%3A//images.google.com/%3Fgws_rd%3Dssl&c=UTF-8&d=The%20page%20you%20are%20trying%20to%20view%20cannot%20be%20shown%20because%20it%20uses%20an%20invalid%20or%20unsupported%20form%20of%20compression.

I would be very grateful for any thoughts and advice what exactly might be the problem and at least approximately what should be paid attention to.

I'm using:

```
debian
firefox-esr
selenium == 4.2.0
geckodriver-v0.31.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Reached error page: about:neterror?e=contentEncodingError&u=https%3A//images.google.com/%3Fgws_rd%3Dssl&c=UTF-8&d=The%20page%20you%20are%20trying%20to%20view%20cannot%20be%20shown%20because%20it%20uses%20an%20invalid%20or%20unsupported%20form%20of%20compression.
```

...implies that there are some configuration settings mismatch while [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) initiates/spawns a new *Browsing Context* i.e. [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) session and is often observed as:

[image: Content Encoding Error]

---

### Solution

As per the [mozilla support docs](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1163431)  you need to try out the following steps:

- Try to reset the `network.http.accept-encoding` prefs on the **`about:config`** page in case they show as user set (bold). You can open the [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) page via the location/address bar. You can accept the warning and click `"I'll be careful"` to continue.
- If you are having ***Avast Antivirus*** or ***Malwarebytes*** installed, you may need to disable those in the test machine before executing the tests.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! But I don't really understand how can I reset the `network.http.accept-encoding` prefs through `Selenium`. And I don't use neither Avast Antivirus nor Malwarebytes.

Comment: I'm asking this because I need to run certain tests in docker so I won't be able to manually change `network.http.accept-encoding` prefs each time.

Comment: Reset `network.http.accept-encoding` manually, you may like to restart the test system as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand. How to do it if I use headless browser without a graphical UI?

Comment: Ahh, first things first please remove `options.set_capability('marionette', False)`. Using **marionette** is mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I removed this line, but unfortunately it did not help to solve the problem yet.

Comment: Can you reinstall the browser so the default settings are enforced. Haven't been able to reproduce the issue on ESR headless build.