# WebDriverError@chrome instead of WebDriverError@firefox while using Firefox browser with selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I'm trying to write several tests using `selenium`, but I'm seeing the following strange behavior.
When I run the tests like this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

options = FirefoxOptions()
service = Service()

brow = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
brow.execute("get", {'url': 'https://python.org'})
```

I get the result I expected, the `python.org` website is opened in **Firefox** browser.

But if I make a mistake in URL, I'm getting the following error:

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

options = FirefoxOptions()
service = Service()

brow = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
brow.execute("get", {'url': 'qwerty'})
```

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Malformed URL: URL constructor: qwerty is not a valid URL.
Stacktrace:
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:186:5
InvalidArgumentError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:315:5
GeckoDriver.prototype.navigateTo@chrome://remote/content/marionette/driver.js:804:11
```

I just want to understand why I see here `WebDriverError@chrome`, and not `WebDriverError@firefox` or something like that.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's probably, how selenium code is written internally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These error messages...

```
WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:186:5
InvalidArgumentError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:315:5
GeckoDriver.prototype.navigateTo@chrome://remote/content/marionette/driver.js:804:11
```

containing the phrase *`@chrome`* may leave an impression of a strange behavior while using [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) and [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) combo.

However, as per @AutomatedTester's comment in the [GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/787) discussion [Selenium 3.4.0-GeckoDriver 0.17.0 : GeckoDriver producing logs through Chromium/Chrome modules #787](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/787#issuecomment-309121379):

> > These errors are nothing to worry about. Mozilla uses different open source projects to build Firefox for different reasons. It showing Chrome errors means nothing in the big picture.

So you can ignore them safely.