# Upgrading Selenium version to 4.8.3 throws java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, noclassdeffounderror

After I've upgraded Selenium version to `4.8.3` I'm no longer able to run my tests as I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotVisibleException
```

Has anyone encountered this issue and knows a fix? I'm using Intelij.

It is definitely something related to the Selenium version. I want to upgrade so I am able to run the tests locally again as with old selenium versions I'm receiving the `java.io.IOException: Invalid Status code=403 text=Forbidden`

Answer (score 0):

### Using *Firefox* and *GeckoDriver*

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.10.0***, [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) ***v0.33.0*** and [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) ***v114.0.1*** you can use the minimum code block:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/");
```

Console Output:

```
Jun 11, 2023 3:58:24 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output
```

---

### Using *Chrome* and *ChromeDriver*

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.10.0***, [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) ***v114.0*** and [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) ***v114.0*** you can use the minimum code block:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/");
```

Console Output:

```
Jun 11, 2023 3:58:24 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not working for me. It is resulting in java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/ElementNotVisibleException