# How to initialize firefox with a Selenium Java project using Java 20

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver, java-20

Which version of geckodriver should I use for Java version 20 and selenium  v4.10.0 ?
while my firefox is 114. when I use geckodriver 0.33.0 I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.NoSuchDriverException: geckodriver located at path, but invalid
```

Answer (score 0):

### Initializing *Firefox* with *GeckoDriver*

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.10.0***, [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) ***v0.33.0*** and [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) ***v114.0.1*** you can use the minimum code block:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/");
```

Console Output:

```
Jun 11, 2023 3:58:24 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder getLogOutput
INFO: Driver logs no longer sent to console by default; https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/drivers/service/#setting-log-output
```