# Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output: console.error: JsonSchemaValidator.jsm:

Tags: selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, selenium-java

When I execute a Selenium Script using Firefox, the Firefox opens up but it doesn't redirect to the URL. Below is the error which is displayed on the Eclipse Console:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
console.error: JsonSchemaValidator.jsm
```

my script is below :

```java
package testCases;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Authentication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/usine-dev/workdir/workspace/test-bleu-horizon/src/test/resources/drivers/geckodriver.exe" );
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://github.com/");
    }
}
```

I am using `selenium-java-4.10.0.jar`, and `geckodriver (v0.32.0 )` 
`firefox 102.9.0esr (32 bits)`, `windows 10`

And I have tried all the version but I usually have the same error

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using selenium `v4.10.0`, you don't really have to set the path of `driver.exe` any more. Selenium's new module known as `SeleniumManager` will do the job of handling browsers and browser drivers for you.

Remove the below line and try, see if that resolves the issue:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:/usine-dev/workdir/workspace/test-bleu-horizon/src/test/resources/drivers/geckodriver.exe" );
```

Just keep it like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://github.com/");
    }
```

**UPDATE:** If despite doing above it doesn't work, update `firefox` to the latest one and retry if that solves the issue.

Comment: Even without driver.exe i have the same error

Comment: Check the update in the answer, worth trying that.

Answer (score 0):

The plain vanila [***Firefox***](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and the [***Firefox Extended Support Release or Rapid Release***](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/enterprise/) aren't the same.

---

### Solution

To open the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) driven [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) initiated [Firefox Extended Support Release or Rapid Release](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-esr-release-cycle) browsing context you need to pass the absolute location of the ***firefox x.y.z ESR*** binary through `setBinary()` method of the *`FirefoxOptions`* object as follows:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\path\\to\\firefoxESR.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://github.com/");
```